# JSONException in Android , how to solve?

Tags: android, json

I have this following JSON string and i want extract the json array into separate string using android but i facing JSON exception.

```
       try 
       {


         String str="[{'Festivals':{'Fesa1':'english is good ','Fesb1':'my english is not so accurate','Fesa2':'oriya is very nice language','Fesb2':'my oriya is absolutely good','Fesa3':'cricket is a very popular game ','Fesb3':'cricket is life for indian','Fesa4':'hockey is the original game for india','Fesb4':'hockey needs to improve ','Fesa5':'computer is a very functional device','Fesb5':'computer is very helpful to mankind'}}] "; 

         JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);

         String abc1=null;

         String abc2=null;

         String abc3=null;

         int i2=0;

         for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
         {

             JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

             JSONObject jsonObject = e.getJSONObject("Festivals");

             tt.setText(tt.getText().toString()+String.valueOf("Total Array Length: "+jsonArray.length()+"\n"));        

             for(int i1=0;i1<jsonObject.length();i1++)
             {

                 i2=i1+1;

                abc1=jsonObject.getString("Fesa"+i2);

                abc2=jsonObject.getString("Fesb"+i2);


                tt.setText(tt.getText().toString()+String.valueOf(abc1+" - "+abc2+" - "+" \n"));        

            }





         }      



    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {

        tt.setText("JSON Exception");


    }
```

So , i am getting JSONExcepiton error. Please help me out. Please suggest me some solution

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: make sure the json is valid . check it @ http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid. Check it @ http://jsonlint.com/

It should be

```
[   // json array node
    {  // json object node
        "abc": { // json object abc
            "name": "andy", 
            "blood": "o+",
            "ge": 45
        }
    }
]
```

Parsing

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray("your jsonstring");
for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jarray.get(i);
JSONObject jb1 = jb.getJSONObject("abc");
String name = jb1.getString("name");
// similarly blood and use getInt for ge
}
```

Edit:

Change your json to below and use the below you will get all values

```
String jsonstring ="{"
        +"abc"+": ["
            +"{"
               + "Fesa"+":"+ "englishisgood"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+ "myenglishisnotsoaccurate"
            +"},"
             +"{"
               + "Fesa"+":"+ "germanisverynicelanguage"
            +"}"+","
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+ "mygermanisabsolutelygood"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+ "cricketisaverypopulargame"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+ "cricketislifeforindian"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+  "hockeyistheoriginalgameforindia"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+  "hockeyneedstoimprove"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+  "computerisaveryfunctionaldevice"
           +"},"
           +"{"
                +"Fesa"+":"+  "computerisveryhelpfultomankind"
            +"},"
        +"]"+
    "}";
```

Parsing

```
    try
    {
    JSONObject jsb = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
    JSONArray jarray =jsb.getJSONArray("abc");
    for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
    {
    JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jarray.get(i);
    String name = jb.getString("Fesa");
    Log.i("..........",name);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, 1000).show();
    }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes but in ANDROID string character is not allowing double quote string values so , how to give valid JSON string.

Comment: no man it's giving error. we can't give single quote in a string variable in Android. String str=' '; error will come invalid character constant ....

Comment: please suggest me how can i write json string value in Android string variable.

Comment: This is the error string -: String str="{"abc":[{"Fesa1":"english is good "},{"Fesb1":"my english is not so accurate"},{"Fesa2":"german is very nice language"},{"Fesb2":"my german is absolutely good"},{"Fesa3":"cricket is a very popular game "},{"Fesb3":"cricket is life for indian"},{"Fesa4":"hockey is the original game for india"},{"Fesb4":"hockey needs to improve "},{"Fesa5":"computer is a very functional device"},{"Fesb5":"computer is very helpful to mankind"}]}";  i have written the json string value inside str variable but it's giving error.

Comment: @user2551103 if you are duplicating your question its wrong. pls avoid it and post all your codes by editing yor post in the question part

Comment: @user2551103 you need to change the json and also see the update of how to have it as a string. If you duplicate your question it will deleted

Comment: yes thank you for the solution it's working fine but the problem is if i am trying to do a mysql table into JSON string then how can get this structure as you have suggested , so that i can use the JSON string in Android to extract the values....

Comment: @user2551103 only 1 question at a time. Post a new question. This question is solved. Accept this one and start a new question in separate thread. Can't answer everything under this question and if oyu edit the originality of the question is lost

Comment: ok but i want you should answer to that... i posting a new thread in few minuets...

Comment: @user2551103 first accept this one. secondly why do you need json. You make a query and get the data required from mysql table. thirdly i will answer if i know the solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure JSON is valid as the answer above. In case of any special characters you will need to escape them, i.e.

```
\" instead of "
```