# How to give JSON string value to Android String Variable?

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON string and i want to assign the JSON string into Android string variable to extract the JSON object into separated string.

```
String str="{"abc":[{"Fesa1":"english is good "},{"Fesb1":"my english is not so accurate"},{"Fesa2":"german is very nice language"},{"Fesb2":"my german is absolutely good"},{"Fesa3":"cricket is a very popular game "},{"Fesb3":"cricket is life for indian"},{"Fesa4":"hockey is the original game for india"},{"Fesb4":"hockey needs to improve "},{"Fesa5":"computer is a very functional device"},{"Fesb5":"computer is very helpful to mankind"}]}";
```

While giving the JSON string value into **str** variable , it's giving error. and we can't give single quote into JSON string so how to solve this conflict.

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Put before every quote back slash \

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONException in Android , how to solve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649650/jsonexception-in-android-how-to-solve)

Comment: @Raghunandan: No; that's about parsing an almost-JSON string that uses single quotes rather than double quotes. This question is about using quotes inside a Java script that just happens to represent JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the below

```
String jsonstring = "{"
        +"abc"+": ["
            +"{"
               + "Fesa1"+":"+ "englishisgood"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesb1"+":"+ "myenglishisnotsoaccurate"
            +"},"
             +"{"
               + "Fesa2"+":"+ "germanisverynicelanguage"
            +"}"+","
            +"{"
                +"Fesb2"+":"+ "mygermanisabsolutelygood"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa3"+":"+ "cricketisaverypopulargame"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesb3"+":"+ "cricketislifeforindian"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa4"+":"+  "hockeyistheoriginalgameforindia"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesb4"+":"+  "hockeyneedstoimprove"
            +"},"
            +"{"
                +"Fesa5"+":"+  "computerisaveryfunctionaldevice"
           +"},"
           +"{"
                +"Fesb5"+":"+  "computerisveryhelpfultomankind"
            +"},"
        +"]"+
    "}";
```

Comment: i don't know , i don't have that much of reputation to give vote to an answer....

Comment: @user2551103 never mind its ok. i just wanted to know what was wrong

Answer (score 2):

it is like this :

```
String json = "{\"username\":\""+username+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\"}";
```

tested and working on my android app

Answer (score 1):

Use [link here](http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html) to escape your JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters (i.e. \") in your JSON string.

Here it is the correct version:

```
String str = "{\"abc\":[{\"Fesa1\":\"english is good \"},{\"Fesb1\":\"my english is not so accurate\"},{\"Fesa2\":\"german is very nice language\"},{\"Fesb2\":\"my german is absolutely good\"},{\"Fesa3\":\"cricket is a very popular game \"},{\"Fesb3\":\"cricket is life for indian\"},{\"Fesa4\":\"hockey is the original game for india\"},{\"Fesb4\":\"hockey needs to improve \"},{\"Fesa5\":\"computer is a very functional device\"},{\"Fesb5\":\"computer is very helpful to mankind\"}]}";
```

Cheers!